# Java DTO as Data Request Model - scope of model vs layers

Tags: java, spring, model, architecture

TL;DR
Can I use one data model for `@Controller` and several `@Services`?

Imagine I have spring `@Controller`, which expects request model via `@RequestBody` - eg `PersonModel model`. I want to register the person.

I am calling service from endpoint by `service.register(personModel)`.

PersonService in the register method do some stuff, eg:
`emailService.sendEmail(personModel)`
`statisticService.register(personModel)`, etc

Question:
As you see, the model is used in many services in many different layers. It's very convenient but is it ok? Or maybe I should "clone" model and create each model per layer, eg `PersonModelEmail` , `PersonModelStatistic`?

Some references to books or articles would be more than welcome.